# Amber Crecto: preload association with LEFT JOIN

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

I have 2 models: Task and TaskLimit. Task belongs to TaskLimit. But task_limit_id might be Nil, so I need to use LEFT JOIN to preload existing TaskLimit's.
The only way I can do join is this:

`query = query.join(:task_limit).preload(:task_limit)`

But It doesn't select Tasks without TaskLimit.
There is a method in source code of Query class, where I can specify String for my JOIN:

`def self.join(join_string : String)
        self.new.join(join_string)
      end`

But When I try to use it:

`query.join("LEFT JOIN task_limits ON tasks.task_limit_id = task_limits.id").preload(:task_limit)`

I get an error that the method doesn't exist:

> in tmp/1537794230627_console.cr:2: no overload matches 'Crecto::Repo::Query#join' with type String
>   Overloads are:
>    - Crecto::Repo::Query#join(join_associations : Array(Symbol))
>    - Crecto::Repo::Query#join(join_association : Symbol)
>
> query = query.join("LEFT JOIN task_limits ON tasks.task_limit_id = task_limits.id").preload(:task_limit).where(id: [43, 46])

How can I preload association with LEFT JOIN?